# What's the recommended way to filter on an index using multiple parameters in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What's the best way to do this query in neo4j?

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('type:x AND id:123456')
RETURN n
```

or

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(type="x")
WHERE n.id=123456
RETURN n
```

I have both properties auto-indexed and both queries take more or less the same time (the 2nd option tended to be faster on the 1st run but I'd have to do thorough tests to be sure).

So, any reason one should be used over the other?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Nicholas so basically use the 1st option which will be faster as more data is added to the db. Thanks :) If you add it as as answer i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, it's faster. I don't have hard numbers, but I think I've highlighted the difference enough. Also, if you are going to be doing this `type` filter, you may want to think about creating your  own index call index `x` which only stores nodes of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene should be pretty flat timing once you start to scale.

That's the key in the timing is that the second query, you will have to scan through ALL of type X to find the one with the ID of 123456, versus the first, which should be more efficient, as well as looks better IMO.